# how to auto start a new line when text too long

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, hyphenation

Today I encount a problem, some words did not start a new line and out of the docs like this:

[image]

what should I do to make it start a new line automatic? This is my text:

```
结果发现有2条已经读取但是未处理的消息。起始ID是1620709698075-0和1620710703039-0。消费Stream消息时，提示错误Redis command timed out; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out after 1 minute。
```

Comment: there has to be space between the words otherwise how will the program know where to break the line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions:

- disable justification for the paragraph in question
- load the `xurl` package and encase the overly long strings in `\url{...}` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{xcolor}   % for \textcolor command
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \RaggedRight command
\usepackage{xurl}     % for \url and \urlstyle commands
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{Problem:}

结果发现有2条已经读取但是未处理的消息。起始ID是1620709698075-0和1620710703039-0。
消费Stream消息时，提示错误Redis command timed out; nested exception is 
io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: 
io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out after 1 minute。

\bigskip
\textcolor{red}{Solution 1: \texttt{\string\raggedright} or \texttt{\string\RaggedRight} within a TeX group}

\begingroup\raggedright\hspace{12pt}
结果发现有2条已经读取但是未处理的消息。起始ID是1620709698075-0和1620710703039-0。
消费Stream消息时，提示错误Redis command timed out; nested exception is 
io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: 
io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out after 1 minute。
\par\endgroup

\bigskip
\textcolor{red}{Solution 2: Selectively encase long strings in \texttt{\string\url} directives}

结果发现有2条已经读取但是未处理的消息。起始ID是1620709698075-0和1620710703039-0。
消费Stream消息时，提示错误Redis command timed out; nested exception is 
io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: 
\url{io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException:} Command timed out after 1 minute。

\end{document}
```