# Automatic Report Printer: Handle long technical expressions in TOC and legend entries

Tags: pgfplots, table-of-contents, legend

I'm currently programming a automatic printer with Latex for some technical reports. The whole printer can be controlled and launched from an external programm which provides csv-files and Data which are processed with Pgfplots to different standardized plots in a Report- or Beamer Format.
My problem however comes along with very long automatic generated file names. As the report is meant for  for technical measurements the file names or legend entries can be labeled as File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239 or similar. This gives me several problems as Latex isn't able to break those names in both the TOC and in the pgfplots legend entry.

Is there any way to force Latex to break those long label into multiline? Unfortunately the code is a bit longer to provide a full working example but anyways the problem should be (from my udnerstanding) independent from the plotfile function. Adjustbox is used to squeeze big pgfplotstable plots for both the Report or Beamer formats.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{graphicx, siunitx}  
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% ======== Commands ========
\newcommand{\comma}{/pgf/number format/read comma as period}
\newcommand{\semicolon}{semicolon}
\newcommand{\commadelim}{comma}
\newcommand{\type}{commadelim}

% ======== Plotfile ========
\newcommand{\plotfile}[3]{
    \edef\rememberuscatcode{% make the underscore into a printable symbol,
        \catcode`_=\the\catcode`_   
        \let\noexpand\rememberuscatcode\relax
    }
    \catcode`_=12           % but first remember its meaning
    %
    % Write correct column seperator
    \newcommand{\tempmacro}{#3} 
    \ifx\tempmacro\semicolon
        \renewcommand{\type}{semicolon}
    \fi 
    \ifx\tempmacro\commadelim
        \renewcommand{\type}{comma}
    \fi  
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=\type]
    {\detokenize{#1}}{\table} 
    \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\table}
    \renewcommand{\tempmacro}{#2}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofcols{%Define max. Nr of used columns  
        \ifx\tempmacro\undefined 
            {\pgfplotsretval-1}
        \else
            {#2}
        \fi         
    }%
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\numberofcols}{
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{##1}\of{\table}\to{\colname}
        \addplot table [y index=##1, \comma] {\table};
        \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname}
    }%
    \rememberuscatcode
}%

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \begin{filecontents}    {File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239.csv}  
        Entry1;Entry_With_Different_Settings;Entry2_With_Different_Settings
        0,25;0;0
        4;75;76
        9;70;70
    \end{filecontents}

    \section{Print}
    \subsection{File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239}
        \begin{figure}[ht]
            \begin{center}
                \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth, pagecenter, 
                    max totalheight = 0.74\textheight, max width = 0.9\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \begin{axis}[
                            width=0.82\linewidth, height=0.48\linewidth, 
                            grid=major, grid style={dashed,gray!30},
                            xlabel=X Axis, 
                            x unit=\si{\volt \per \meter},
                            xmin = 0, xmax = 9,
                            ylabel=Y Axis,  y unit=\si{\milli \ampere},
                            legend pos=outer north east, legend cell align={left},      
                        ]
                        \addplot[mark=none, red, dashed] coordinates {(0,100) (10,100)};                 
                        \addplot[mark=none, red, dashed,forget plot] coordinates {(0,30) (10,25)};      
                        \addlegendentry{\footnotesize Limit}
                        %
                        \plotfile{File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239.csv}{2}{semicolon}
                        %
                        \end{axis}
                    \end{tikzpicture}           
                \end{adjustbox}
            \end{center}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I presume you mean with advice beyond the trivial "make the legend labels shorter" or "make your graph narrower".

Comment: Using some kind of `\url` as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596714/how-to-auto-start-a-new-line-when-text-too-long may help, so that the things can be broken into lines. Also, you can put the graph legend *below* the graph

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. And yeah, caused by the restrains that the data is provided from an automatic test-program I'm not able to change the labels. Also I'm not able to enter manual-linebreaks with \\ as the label are read from the csv-files. Moreless automatic linebreakers would be needed if the label exceeds the given limits. Unfortunately adjustbox doesn't count the legend in...

Comment: @Rmano I will try \url. Legend below the graph is no option as the same code is used also for the beamer documentclass. If then multiple csv-entries need to be ploted the resulting plot is not easily readable...

Comment: \url unfortunately doesn't work caused by a exceeded TeX capacity (maybe caused by the "_" )...

Comment: Please make your code self contained so that it can be copied and compiled. Put  (a portion of) the .csv file inside `\begin{filecontents}{foo.csv} put the csv cotent here \end{filecontents}`. And replace `\include{TestSuite_Packages}` with the packages strictly needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added the missing functions, unfortunately now the code is much longer but the example should be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version uses the url package.  Mostly you just need to use `\protect\url` to avoid expanding it too soon.  I also played with the legend to restrict the text width, and added a gap between entries.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{graphicx, siunitx}  
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{url}

% ======== Commands ========
\newcommand{\comma}{/pgf/number format/read comma as period}
\newcommand{\semicolon}{semicolon}
\newcommand{\commadelim}{comma}
\newcommand{\type}{commadelim}

% ======== Plotfile ========
\newcommand{\plotfile}[3]{
    \edef\rememberuscatcode{% make the underscore into a printable symbol,
        \catcode`_=\the\catcode`_   
        \let\noexpand\rememberuscatcode\relax
    }
    \catcode`_=12           % but first remember its meaning
    %
    % Write correct column seperator
    \newcommand{\tempmacro}{#3} 
    \ifx\tempmacro\semicolon
        \renewcommand{\type}{semicolon}
    \fi 
    \ifx\tempmacro\commadelim
        \renewcommand{\type}{comma}
    \fi  
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=\type]
    {\detokenize{#1}}{\table} 
    \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\table}
    \renewcommand{\tempmacro}{#2}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofcols{%Define max. Nr of used columns  
        \ifx\tempmacro\undefined 
            {\pgfplotsretval-1}
        \else
            {#2}
        \fi         
    }%
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\numberofcols}{
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{##1}\of{\table}\to{\colname}
        \addplot table [y index=##1, \comma] {\table};
        \addlegendentryexpanded[text width=1in, text depth=]{\protect\url{\colname}}
        \addlegendimage{empty legend}
        \addlegendentry{}
    }%
    \rememberuscatcode
}%

\begin{document}
    {\sloppy\tableofcontents}

    \begin{filecontents}    {File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239.csv}  
        Entry1;Entry_With_Different_Settings;Entry2_With_Different_Settings
        0,25;0;0
        4;75;76
        9;70;70
    \end{filecontents}

    \section{Print}
    \subsection{\protect\url{File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239}}
    
        \begin{figure}[ht]
            \begin{center}
                \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth, pagecenter, 
                    max totalheight = 0.74\textheight, max width = 0.9\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \begin{axis}[
                            width=0.82\linewidth, height=0.48\linewidth, 
                            grid=major, grid style={dashed,gray!30},
                            xlabel=X Axis, 
                            x unit=\si{\volt \per \meter},
                            xmin = 0, xmax = 9,
                            ylabel=Y Axis,  y unit=\si{\milli \ampere},
                            legend pos=outer north east, legend cell align={left},      
                        ]
                        \addplot[mark=none, red, dashed] coordinates {(0,100) (10,100)};                 
                        \addplot[mark=none, red, dashed,forget plot] coordinates {(0,30) (10,25)};      
                        \addlegendentry{\footnotesize Limit}
                        %
                        \plotfile{File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239.csv}{2}{semicolon}
                        %
                        \end{axis}
                    \end{tikzpicture}           
                \end{adjustbox}
            \end{center}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

This performs a test to determine if the column names are longer than 1in.  I had to move most of the pgfplotstable code outside the tikzpicture for it to work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{graphicx, siunitx}  
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{url}

\newsavebox{\urlbox}
\newif\iflongcolnames

% ======== Commands ========
\newcommand{\comma}{/pgf/number format/read comma as period}
\newcommand{\semicolon}{semicolon}
\newcommand{\commadelim}{comma}
\newcommand{\type}{commadelim}

% ======== Plotfile ========
\newcommand{\plotfile}{
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,...,\numberofcols}{
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{##1}\of{\table}\to{\colname}
        \addplot table [y index=##1, \comma] {\table};
        \iflongcolnames
          \addlegendentryexpanded[text width=1in, text depth=]{\protect\url{\colname}}
          \addlegendimage{empty legend}
          \addlegendentry{}
        \else
          \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname}
        \fi
    }%
}%
% ====== preview ++++++
\newcommand{\preview}[3]{%
    \edef\rememberuscatcode{% make the underscore into a printable symbol,
        \catcode`_=\the\catcode`_   
        \let\noexpand\rememberuscatcode\relax
    }
    \catcode`_=12           % but first remember its meaning
    %
    % Write correct column seperator
    \newcommand{\tempmacro}{#3}%
    \ifx\tempmacro\semicolon
        \renewcommand{\type}{semicolon}%
    \fi 
    \ifx\tempmacro\commadelim
        \renewcommand{\type}{comma}%
    \fi  
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=\type]%
    {\detokenize{#1}}{\table} %
    \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\table}%
    \renewcommand{\tempmacro}{#2}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofcols{%Define max. Nr of used columns  
        \ifx\tempmacro\undefined 
            0
        \else
            {#2}
        \fi         
    }%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\numberofcols}{%
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{\i}\of{\table}\to{\colname}%
        \savebox{\urlbox}{\colname}%
        \ifdim\wd\urlbox > 1in\relax
          \global\longcolnamestrue
        \fi
    }%
    \rememberuscatcode
}%
\begin{document}
    {\sloppy\tableofcontents}

    \begin{filecontents}    {File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239.csv}  
        Entry1;Entry_With_Different_Settings;Entry2_With_Different_Settings
        0,25;0;0
        4;75;76
        9;70;70
    \end{filecontents}

    \section{Print}
    \subsection{\protect\url{File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239}}
    
        \begin{figure}[ht]
            \preview{File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239.csv}{2}{semicolon}
                \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth, pagecenter, 
                    max totalheight = 0.74\textheight, max width = 0.9\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \begin{axis}[
                            width=0.82\linewidth, height=0.48\linewidth, 
                            grid=major, grid style={dashed,gray!30},
                            xlabel=X Axis, 
                            x unit=\si{\volt \per \meter},
                            xmin = 0, xmax = 9,
                            ylabel=Y Axis,  y unit=\si{\milli \ampere},
                            legend pos=outer north east, legend cell align={left},      
                        ]
                        \addplot[mark=none, red, dashed] coordinates {(0,100) (10,100)};                 
                        \addplot[mark=none, red, dashed,forget plot] coordinates {(0,30) (10,25)};      
                        \addlegendentry{\footnotesize Limit}
                        %
                        \plotfile
                        %
                        \end{axis}
                    \end{tikzpicture}           
                \end{adjustbox}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi John, your approach works quite well for me, especially with long legend entries.. The only problem which is left comes along with very short legend entries where the given legend width is to large and since it looks a bit of... Is there any way to simple implement a max width function for the legend width?

Comment: varwidth makes the Deal. Thanks for your Input

Answer (score 0):

The question really has two issues: the long titles in the sectioning, and the long legend widths.

To address the sectioning, I set up a macro `\breakabledef` that will create a `\def` except that underscores will be replaced with `\_` and `\allowbreak` is inserted after every non-space/non-macro character.  Then, just use this defined macro as the section title.

As to the plot legends, I don't know enough about `tikz` to alter the legend location or linebreaking on the plot.  But I will note that the combination of the `center` environment was fighting with the `adjustbox`, and so I eliminated/changed a few things there, to bring it back to center.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{graphicx, siunitx}  
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% ======== Commands ========
\newcommand{\comma}{/pgf/number format/read comma as period}
\newcommand{\semicolon}{semicolon}
\newcommand{\commadelim}{comma}
\newcommand{\type}{commadelim}

% ======== Plotfile ========
\newcommand{\plotfile}[3]{
    \edef\rememberuscatcode{% make the underscore into a printable symbol,
        \catcode`_=\the\catcode`_   
        \let\noexpand\rememberuscatcode\relax
    }
    \catcode`_=12           % but first remember its meaning
    %
    % Write correct column seperator
    \newcommand{\tempmacro}{#3} 
    \ifx\tempmacro\semicolon
        \renewcommand{\type}{semicolon}
    \fi 
    \ifx\tempmacro\commadelim
        \renewcommand{\type}{comma}
    \fi  
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=\type]
    {\detokenize{#1}}{\table} 
    \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\table}
    \renewcommand{\tempmacro}{#2}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofcols{%Define max. Nr of used columns  
        \ifx\tempmacro\undefined 
            {\pgfplotsretval-1}
        \else
            {#2}
        \fi         
    }%
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\numberofcols}{
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{##1}\of{\table}\to{\colname}
        \addplot table [y index=##1, \comma] {\table};
        \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname}
    }%
    \rememberuscatcode
}%

\usepackage{tokcycle}

\newcommand\breakabledef[2]{%
  \resettokcycle
  \Characterdirective{\ifx_##1\addcytoks{\_}\else\addcytoks{##1}\fi
    \addcytoks{\allowbreak}}%
  \tokcyclexpress{#2}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\the\cytoks}%
}

\begin{document}
\breakabledef\mycsv
  {File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239}

    \tableofcontents

    \begin{filecontents}[overwrite]    {File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239.csv}  
        Entry1;Entry_With_Different_Settings;Entry2_With_Different_Settings
        0,25;0;0
        4;75;76
        9;70;70
    \end{filecontents}

    \section{Print}
    \subsection{\mycsv}
        \begin{figure}[ht]
%            \begin{center}
                \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=.9\textwidth, pagecenter, 
                    max totalheight = 0.74\textheight, max width = 0.8\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \begin{axis}[
                            width=0.82\linewidth, height=0.48\linewidth, 
                            grid=major, grid style={dashed,gray!30},
                            xlabel=X Axis, 
                            x unit=\si{\volt \per \meter},
                            xmin = 0, xmax = 9,
                            ylabel=Y Axis,  y unit=\si{\milli \ampere},
                           legend pos=outer north east, 
                            legend cell align={left},      
                        ]
                        \addplot[mark=none, red, dashed] coordinates {(0,100) (10,100)};                 
                        \addplot[mark=none, red, dashed,forget plot] coordinates {(0,30) (10,25)};      
                        \addlegendentry{\footnotesize Limit}
                        %
                        \plotfile{File_Testname_3V6_1V7_Remeasure_Operator1_Operator2_D20210512T102239.csv}{2}{semicolon}
                        %
                        \end{axis}
                    \end{tikzpicture}           
                \end{adjustbox}
%            \end{center}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer, especially for the fighting center and adjustbox input. However, the version with url/sloppy is easier to use as I have a lot of different filenames/subsection were I always would need to use the macro.